# how to apply color to active link and remove from other link in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

When i click on a link, its color should change, and it should be same until i press other link, i know how to do it in javascript but i don't know how to do it in react

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import ToggleBtn from '../sidedrwaer/ToggleBtn';

const Navbar=(props)=> {
    return (
        <header className="head">
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="navbar-logo">
                    <img src="/images/moviologo.svg" alt="logo"/>
                </div>
               {window.innerWidth>576?<div className="navbar-items">
                    <ul>
                        <Link to="/"><li className="active" >HOME</li></Link>
                        <Link to="/lineup"><li>LINE UP</li></Link>
                        <Link to="/faq"><li>FAQ</li></Link>
                        <Link to="/contactus"><li>CONTACT US</li></Link>
                    </ul>
               </div>:null}
                {window.innerWidth<=576?<div className="toggle-container">
                    <ToggleBtn onClick={props.onClickhandler}/>
                </div>:null}
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}
export default Navbar;
```

```css
.active{
    color:#DF001A;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `NavLink` instead of `link`

```
Example : 
  <NavLink to={link} activeClassName={class name } exact >{children}</NavLink>
```

Comment: what is activeClassname?

Comment: `activeClassname`  name of your class you want to add   `.active`